# How to create a Input box with a functioning cancel button and a ability to have a default value

Tags: delphi, input, inputbox

When using a `InputBox` I can add a default value for the text field. Like this:

```
inputbox('value Enter', 'enter a value', 'default value');
```

Unfortunately, the cancel button can not be used properly. When cancel is pressed, the `inputbox` gives the default value. Which is not ideal.

There also exists a 'inputquery' dialog, which has a functioning dialog, but no options for a default value.

```
inputquery('Title', 'enter a value', variabile1);
```

This pretty much leaves the only option of designing a new form to use as a dialog, but that is also not ideal.

Is there a dialog which has a functioning cancel button and a option for default values?

Comment: The difference between the two is that `InputQuery` returns `True` if user clicks `OK`, and  `False` if user clicks `Cancel` or presses `Esc`. Therefore you get an unambiguous response with `InputQuery`.

Comment: No: another option is to initialize variables **oneself**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the `InputQuery` function *does* allow you to set a default value:

```pascal
var S := 'Sir Anthony Frogkins';
if InputQuery('Frog Simulator', 'Please enter the name of the frog:', S) then
  ShowMessageFmt('Frog name: %s', [S]);
```

In fact, from the documentation of the [`InputQuery`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) function:

> `Value` is the value that appears in the edit box when the dialog box first appears and which returns the value that the user enters.

So you could have realised this even without asking at Stack Overflow! I think this is why every computer programming course in the world<sup>1</sup> starts with the same, important lesson: "Always read the documentation of the API you are using."

---

<sup>1</sup> My imaginary dream world.

Comment: Reading the documentation has been tricky for the past few days because emba's docwiki site is down

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am aware of that. But you can always just press the F1 key inside the IDE to open your offline copy.

Comment: I never install it because it takes an eternity to open, at least for me

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It was incredibly slow for me too a few years ago, when the Microsoft Documentation Explorer was used (IIRC). Now, in 10.x at least, the help files are ordinary HTML Help *.chm files and pretty lightweight.